# MySql matching most specific person's name

Tags: php, mysql

I am searching a MySql table for the likely match for a specific person. I am using lots of other criteria but assume we are just talking about the given names field.

Say the search value is John William and the table contains 4 rows with name values

```
John
John William 
John William Henry
John Paul
```

The first 3 could be the right person. I want the search to return the one with the closest match to the name I have, which in this case is row 2.

The original code first does an exact match query using the full supplied name(s). If that returns no records it then does a LIKE query using all names with % on the end. If that fails it then does an exact search on the first name only. In the above example the first query returns record 2 which is what is wanted so the other queries are not run.

The problem is if the search name is John William Henry George, you potentially have to do about 5 queries to gradually make the search less specific. The other problem is that the search value could be John W and the file could contain John William which I would want to match. Or vice versa.

Is there some way of doing a single query that will return the closest match please? In other words that will return just row 2 in the above example.

In order of best fit this is what I think a search for John William Henry should match:

```
John William Henry
John William Henry %
John William H
John William H %
John W H
John W H %
John W
John
```

Note that there is no % after the John W because that will match John W B who cannot be the right person.

Ok, new idea to try to make it more efficient. Is it possible to query the results of a previous query with some PHP code in between. I expect not. Pseudo code as follows:

```
$coarse = Mysql search for John%
$count = mysql_num_rows($coarse);
if ($count == 1) { 
   $rec = mysql_fetch_row($coarse);
   return $rec[0];
} 
// Assume that produced 50 records. Now want to search within those only instead of millions

$fine = Mysql search within $coarse results for John William% 
$count = mysql_num_rows($fine);
if ($count == 1) { 
   $rec = mysql_fetch_row($fine);
   return $rec[0];
}
```

I could obviously do the fine search in PHP but is it possible to do it in SQL, or can I maybe do the above with a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided that the simplest approach was to simply do a few searches, starting with the most specific and working down to the least specific.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a stored procedure. Use an IF ELSE, check if EXISTS then use NOT IN to exclude the entries of Query 1.

Note: There is an EXCEPT operator in ANSI SQL but MySQL doesn't support it so you'd use NOT IN to exclude rows of query 1.

Also don't put too much logic in the database/SQL... if you want to get fancy with your name matching I'd select a basic list of matches with SQL then use PHP code (with regular expressions) for the 'fuzzy/best' match or  logic.

Comment: The code did actually do that originally. It searched for exact match on complete name. If it got nothing it then searched for LIKE match on first-name%. It then did all of the comparisons in PHP. I have been trying to make it more efficient by pushing more of the logic up into MySql.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE (@u varchar(max))
    BEGIN
        SET @v_counter = CHAR_LENGTH(@u);
        while @v_counter >0 do
            if (Select count(*) from table where firstName like @u+"%")>0
                @v_counter=0
            else
                Begin
                   @u=substr(@u, 0, -1)
                   @v_counter=char_length(u)
                END            
         end while
SELECT * from table where firstName like @u+"%"
Return
END;
```

This is untested, but should get you where you want to go. It is a procedure that should start with the full name and remove one character at a time to check for the first matching results.

Comment: That is looking promising thanks. One issue. Search value John William. Table value J W. It is going to get right down to just J before it matches. Then it will match thousands of names that do not have initials J W. eg. Julie Mary.

Comment: Actually my example is reversed. It will correctly find John W and then John which are closer matches than finding J W who could be anyone. Where the problem lies is if the search value is J W and the table value is John William. The above will never find him until it reduces to just "J" which will then match thousands of names that do not have a second name starting with W. It also does lots of searches that are never going to be there. eg. Nobody's name is going to be entered as John Willia

Comment: The other problem with the procedure for a search value of John William is that when it shrinks to John W% it will then wrongly match John Walter.

Comment: You could do this for the first and last name, but due to the many possibilities that will make it would be unwise to devote the CPU power to it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a different approach. Have a look into [MySQLs fulltext search capabilities](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html).

Let me give you an easy example to begin with. Lets say your table looks like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE people (
     id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     fullname TEXT,
     FULLTEXT (fullname)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then you can query it like this:

```
SELECT *, 
    MATCH (fullname) AGAINST ('+John William' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS 'Probability'
FROM people
WHERE MATCH (fullname)
AGAINST ('+John William' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY Probability DESC;
```

The [operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html) might have to be slightly altered in order to get your desired result.

Keep in mind, for using fulltext indexes on InnoDB you need a newer version of MySQL. If this is not available, you have to use MyISAM as engine.

Comment: That search will not be run often, whereas the field in question will be used constantly, and is a keyed field, so I would be reluctant to convert it to a fulltext field with the inevitable overheads that would introduce.

Comment: Define _constantly_ . Yes, a fulltext field provides a certain overhead, but unless you have a significant amount of  `INSERT` and `UPDATE`-statements per second and your server and enviroment shouldn't really have any issues with this. Read this article for more details and some sample performance data: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/07/31/innodb-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-part-3/